# sqlite3.OperationalError: 7 values for 9 columns

Tags: python, sqlite

```
p = request.form['Pseudo']

user_check = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM pseudo WHERE user = ?", (p,)).fetchone()
if user_check == None:    
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO pseudo (user, score, win, coup, un, deux, trois, quatre, cinq) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (p,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
    conn.commit()
```

Hello when I run this code I get this error I don't understand
Error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: 7 values for 9 columns
```

my code was working perfectly but I added un, deux, trois, quatre, cinq and now  I can't find my new mistake.

Comment: Are you sure that exact code is executed ? Because it seems OK, have you put some `print` to ensure you use that code ? Does the stacktrace point that exact line (the INSERT  INTO one)

Comment: And do `user_check is None`